# How Can I check if Page is single page of Custom Post Type in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, post, types

On the Homepage I have called the content of Custpm Post Type with Ajax with this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $(".sector_item a").click(function(){
        var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".sector_item_content").html("<div class='load' style='position:relative;margin-top:50px;padding-bottom:50px;'><img src='<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif'></div>");
        $(".sector_item_content").load(post_link);
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

But In the single Page of this same Post Type I need to have another design with content so how I can detect the single page. I tried with Wordpess **is_single()** function but it doesnt work it displayed anyway in ajax.How Can I fix this?
Here is my single template.php

```
<?php if(is_singular('sector' )){
echo 'Single page' ;  
}else{
while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="container single_page_inner">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-10 column" style="float:none;margin:auto;">
                     <div class="sector_single_title">
                        <?php the_title();?>
                     </div>
                     <div class="single_sector_contentmain"> <?php the_content();?></div>
                     <div class="single_sector_more">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo(template_url);?>/images/single_secormoreline.png"/>
                        <div class="single_sector_button">
                            <span class="single_sec_leftline"></span>
                            <span class="single_sec_rightline"></span>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Click Here To Read More</a>
                            <div class="more_line"></div>
                        </div>
                     </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: is_single() tells you if it is a single post, so the problem is probably somewhere else. Show us your template.php.

Comment: Let me see if I understand: (1) You want to be able to show a single page of your custom post type 'sector' using the single.php template, and (2) you also want to be able to get the custom post content using ajax, but without the formatting in single.php. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to do different things when your single.php files is loaded from Ajax, you need to tell it somehow when it is getting an Ajax request.

One approach would be to add a parameter to your call, like this:

```
var post_link = $(this).attr("href") + '?isajax=1';
```

Then in your single.php file, test for this parameter:

```
<?php if(!empty($_GET['isajax'])){
    // This is Ajax - display in Ajax format
} else {
    // This is not Ajax - display in standard single.php format
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
is_singular('YOUR_POST_TYPE' );
```

[CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular)

Comment: It is showing my echo 'Single page', isnt working.I am thinking about how to check it with permalink cause with ajax I am loading the single page.